# Why would my HitTestResultCallback not be called

Tags: c#, wpf, hittest

I've inherited a program that uses hit testing to handle mouse events against a bunch of drawings on a canvas.  Under some circumstances my HitTestResultCallBack stops being called.

Here's where the HitTest is called (this is called from the mousemove event):-

```
internal void HitTest(System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    m_visualTrackerHit = m_visualTrackerHit2 = null;
    Point location = e.GetPosition(this);
    Geometry g = new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(location.X - m_connectDistance, location.Y - m_connectDistance, m_connectDistanceX2, m_connectDistanceX2));
    HitTestParameters parameters = new GeometryHitTestParameters(g);
    HitTestResultCallback callback = new HitTestResultCallback(this.HitTestCallback);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("About to Hit Test");
    VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(this, null, callback, parameters);
}
```

Here's my call back function:-

```
private HitTestResultBehavior HitTestCallback(HitTestResult result)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("HitTestCallBack");
    DrawingVisual visual = result.VisualHit as DrawingVisual;
    if (visual != null)
    {
        VisualTracker visualTracker = visual.GetValue(FrameworkElement.TagProperty) as VisualTracker;
        if (visualTracker != null && visualTracker.Type != VisualType.Selection && visualTracker.Type != VisualType.Ignore)
        {
            if (m_visualTrackerHit == null || visualTracker.Type < m_visualTrackerHit.Type)
            {
                m_visualTrackerHit = visualTracker;
            }
        }
    }
    return HitTestResultBehavior.Continue;
}
```

This all works fine until I take a particular, apparently unrelated action. (In this case each drawing represents a "component" that will have various properties.  Setting a property to an invalid value causes the problem but this is all domain stuff and almost certainly isn't relevant to my question).  Once that action is taken the call back method just stops being called.  N.b. not just for the drawing the property was changed on either, the call back stops getting called for both the canvas and all the objects on it.

I've traced through the code path from the action and can't see anything obvious in there but it's highly complex and I could well have missed something so I'd like to come at this from the other direction.  What are the possible reasons the callback *wouldn't* be called.

I've checked the following:-

The RectangleGeometry is being defined with correct values so it should indicate a collision with the drawing

Nothing is setting IsHitTestVisible to false anywhere.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is mousemove still subscribed and firing, "about to hittest" still being output?

Comment: Yes.  HitTest is firing but HitTestCallBack is not.

Comment: Maybe "this" is not the parent of what is hit. VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(this

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to come back on this as I finally found the answer - or part of it at least.  The property that was set to an invalid value on the component was causing a divide by zero error in the draw method of that component.  That meant that the component was not redrawn but the old drawing of it was left in place, meaning it was not obvious that an error had occurred.

I've tested around this a bit and any unhandled error drawing to the canvas seems to result in the hitTestCallback no longer being called for anything on that canvas.  I don't know why that is but it's easy for me to solve at this point as I can just guard against divide by zero exceptions

Answer (score -1):

Debug your program using [Snoop](https://github.com/snoopwpf/snoopwpf):

1. identify the path of events for a working case
2. identify the path of events for a non-working case
3. once you pinpoint the cause, you can come up with a fix for it

Comment: Thank you.  This looks like exactly the sort of thing I'm after.  Giving it a try and will post back any findings.